# Creating goto links in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have looked around and couldn't find any help on how to make a link to another file in a project using sublime. What I mean is the same as when we use Ctrl+Shift+F to find all the occurrences of a string in the project and in the result there is a link that takes us to the  destination file (on the exact line) for each occurrence.

I would like to use this feature to create a TODO list, for example, things that should be removed before publishing. And it would be very easy using this feature.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [SublimeTODO](https://github.com/robcowie/SublimeTODO). Perhaps it will meet the requirements you have already. If not, you can use it as a reference for how to proceed.